# Is it possible to simulate robots using magnetic wheels driving on a ferrous surface?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all, I'm looking to use Gazebo to simulate a robot using magnetic wheels to drive vertically on ferrous material.
Can anyone please give me some advice if this is possible to do within Gazebo and if so where I should start? I haven't had much luck and I'm pretty new to ROS and Gazebo.
Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15928/is-it-possible-to-simulate-robots-using-magnetic-wheels-driving-on-a-ferrous-surface?/) by [Bizarre_101](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3188/bizarre_101/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think you'll have to write a gazebo plugin, which will calculate and apply magnetic forces to wheels on every time step update.

Here are some links to start with:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=plugins_hello_world

http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html  -- look for setForce method

---

Originally posted by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) with karma: 163 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1